# Command to use instead of sleep() in Calabash

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-ios

I am using calabash automation with Ruby for my project in iOS.

scenario/Ruby:

```
Given(/^I click Login$/) do

  homePage = page(HomePage)

  homePage.loginButton()

  sleep(3)

end

 When(/^I enter valid credentials$/) do

   loginPage = page(LoginPage)

   loginPage.enterEmailaddress()

   loginPage.enterPassword()

   loginPage.done()

   sleep(3)

   loginPage.loginButton()

   sleep(5)

 end
```

As you can see I am using `sleep()` many times
Is there any other command that can be used instead of sleep()

Comment: What exactly are you waiting for, each time you `sleep`? Is there some way you can explicitly wait for these events, rather than waiting 3-5 seconds and hoping for the best?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do differently. Are you waiting for something to happen then continue? Do you just want to delay a certain amount of time? You need to explain the situation better. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages.

Comment: @TomLord :Sorry wasnt clear,I am waiting for the page to load.There is a spinner spinning when the loginButton() is clicked and waiting for the login page to appear.

Comment: @theTinMan:After the done button is clicked,the keyboard is dismissed,so I kept a sleep() for that action.

Comment: As was suggested below, perhaps `await` is all you need. Or, depending on the exact behaviour, perhaps you could explicitly wait for a specific AJAX request to be completed.

Comment: probably I would explain a bit more in detail.I have one page booking widget.my code comes to this page.then the code should wait for the page to load.Then the code should scroll down to enter email address in the text box.Thats my requirement.The script fails as the code is not waiting for page to load and also cannot scroll to the bottom.So I need proper commands to use for this requirement.Many thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the `await` method:

> The await method just returns the page object after waiting for the
>   page to be loaded

As always, read the docs.

https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example#step-2---step-definitions